# Jsp include another jsp with Struts2, but no result

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, include

I used a jsp include another jsp, but I don't get any result, only html tag content.

HelloEmp.jsp: it had iterator value with stuts2 tag.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix = "s" uri = "/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Hello World</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h2>Example of List</h2>  
          <s:iterator value="helloList">
            <s:property /><br/>
         </s:iterator>
   </body>
</html>
```

HelloAction.java: it had a string array

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HelloAction {
   private List<String> helloList = new ArrayList<String>();
   public String execute() throws Exception {
       helloList.add("Jacky");
       helloList.add("Natali");
      return "success";
   }

    public List<String> getHelloList() {
        return helloList;
    }

    public void setHelloList(List<String> helloList) {
        this.helloList = helloList;
    }
}
```

employees.jsp: it included HelloEmp.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix = "s" uri = "/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Employees</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>An example of the include tag: </p>
      <s:include value = "example/HelloEmp.jsp"/>
   </body>
</html>
```

struts.xml:

```
<package name = "helloworld" extends = "struts-default">
      <action name = "hello" class = "example.HelloAction" method = "execute">
         <result name = "success">HelloEmp.jsp</result>
      </action>
</package>
```

When I opened employees.jsp, only can see  tag content in HelloEmp.jsp, I can't see the iterator value:

[image]

But if I directly open HelloEmp.jsp, I got the result:

[image]

Please help me how to fix it? thank you!

Comment: https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/include-tag.html There's no value stack created under `<s:include />`.

Comment: But I am not show how to create value stack, could you give me an example? Do I edit my main page? or included page?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using value use page 
`<jsp:include page="Demo.jsp" />` might work.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I use action tag instead,

`<s:action name="action_name" executeResult="true"/>`

that works for me!
Thank you for you guys.